# access a file with a specific link in django

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

In Django, I have a file foo.txt in my static folder, which can be accessed through www.example.com/static/foo.txt. How would it be possible to access this file by simple doing www.example.com/foo.txt? (without redirections)

thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is a single file it can be possible using your web server directory/file aliases.

Comment: thanks a lot, I used alias on nginx (: it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Selcuk is right, save your file on the server directories, or static files, then simple point the url there

```
<a href="/static/files/foo.txt">Foo Text File</a>
```

Watch your file permissions though